# The widely reported leak of alleged classified US information has demonstrated a serious level of inaccuracy

Tags: sentence-usage

> A spokesperson said in a message posted on Twitter: "**The widely reported leak of alleged classified US information has demonstrated a serious level of inaccuracy**.

[Source](https://www.google.co.kr/amp/s/news.sky.com/story/amp/ministry-of-defence-says-leak-which-claims-uk-special-forces-are-in-ukraine-has-a-serious-level-of-inaccuracy-12855476)

---

If "**leak**" means "a deliberate act of giving secret information to the newspapers, etc.", it wouldn't fit the context because the deliberate act can't demonstrate a serious level of inaccuracy.

Is the boldfaced sentence natural and idiomatic?

Comment: I don't see that sentence as such in your link.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to look at the context of the paragraphs before and after, where it says the leaks shouldn't be taken "at face value". The insinuation here is that although they may be leaks, they may not be accurate leaks, and may have been altered in order to deceive.

One could certainly leak something, but reword it, add to it, or omit details in order to deceive. After reading further it also seems to insinuate that it's somewhat improbable that the US government will ever release the actual documents to confirm what is accurate and what isn't, but they have said "it does appear that the slides have been doctored". To what extent, or whether that is true, we may never know. It would seem the Russians aren't entirely convinced of their authenticity either.

Disclaimer. I'm not saying this article is or isn't true, but it is what the article seems to be about.

Comment: I'd like to ask one more question. Does "**leak**" mean "what has been leaked" or does it mean "a deliberate act of giving secret information to the newspapers, etc."? What exactly does it mean?

Comment: Personally I think it's OK to refer to the documents informally as "the leaks", which is just a short way of saying "the leaked documents", but technically the noun refers to the act.

Answer (score 0):

"The widely reported leak of alleged classified US information has demonstrated a serious level of inaccuracy.

Parse:

"The widely reported leak of alleged classified US information// has demonstrated// a serious level of inaccuracy.

The inaccuracy is about the widely reported leak of the information. In other words, it has been inaccurately reported on.